# Finding the value of a series using a known Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

We are given the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{for }-\dfrac{\pi}{2}<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}\\
0&\text{for }\dfrac{\pi}{2}<x<\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\end{cases}$$
which I have found to have the Fourier series representation,
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)}\cos[(2k-1)x]$$
and using this series, I'm asked to show that
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)}$$
I know that for $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, I have $f(x)=1$, so over this interval,
$$1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)}\cos[(2k-1)x]$$
which gives
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)}\cos[(2k-1)x]$$
How do I deal with the cosine term in the series? If I were to fix $x=0$, which does lie in the first interval, I can guarantee that the cosine term is 1, but is this legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the key to the proof is to choose $x=0$ for which the expression simplifies (the cosines drop out).